# Is there a cheaper way to get money from a Chinese bank account to an Australian bank account than using the bank's SWIFT service?

Tags: australia, international-transfer, china

My friend has arrived in Australia from China to stay for a year on a working holiday visa. He wants to transfer some of his money from his Chinese bank.

If it makes a difference, on the China side it's Bank of China and on the Australia side it's ANZ bank.

I don't know much about the technical stuff and terminology but the obvious way is with something called SWIFT but I'm wondering if there's a cheaper way that the experts here know about that's not common knowledge to normal people.

Comment: To answer this question, we probably need to know how much the banks are charging you. Is it a percentage? A flat fee? Depending on the amount of money, Western Union could be an option.